# If Ethyne has the lowest C-H bond length (highest C-H bond energy) compared to Ethane and Ethene, why is it the most acidic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, acid-base, hybridization, physical-organic-chemistry

I am not an expert in chemistry, but these are the few facts I know from Standard XII chemistry books (these facts could be wrong or incomplete or modified by now).

**Facts I know -**

- Ethane has 'sp$^3$' hybridisation, Ethene has 'sp$^2$', and Ethyne 'sp'.
- The % of 's' orbital present follows in each of the hybridisation
  follows the order sp > sp$^2$ > sp$^3$.
- Since 's' orbital has greater penetration (to the nucleus) depth, the H atom in Ethyne comes the closest to the Carbon atom nucleus than in Ethene and Ethane, hence C-H bond length of Ethyne is the lowest, followed by Ethene and then Ethane.
- On the other hand, since 's' orbital has greater penetration depth, 'sp' hybridised orbitals has the most Electronegativity, followed by 'sp$^2$' and then 'sp$^3$'. Because of this, Ethyne is most acidic, since the carbanion (HC $\equiv$ C $^-$)  is more stable than (H$_2$C = CH$^-$) and (H$_3$C $-$ CH$_2$$^-$). Ethyne can release $H^+$ more easily than Ethene and Ethane, hence Ethyne is most acidic, followed by Ethene and then Ethane.
- Following a similar reasoning of the nature of 's' orbital, one finds that the C-H bond energy of Eythne is the highest, followed by Ethene and then Ethane.

**Question -**

How can Ethyne be the most acidic and yet have the shortest C-H bond length. Isn't there a general rule that **"the shorter the bond length, the stronger the bond strength, and so the weaker the acid"**? Shouldn't shorter X-H bond lengths (X is some atom) mean that X and H has greater bond strength and so it does not dissociate much into $X^-$ and $H^+$ ions, thereby not producing much $H^+$ ions?

Is there something wrong with the **Facts** that I stated or is the **statement of my Question** not true in general?

Comment: Note that names of elements or compounds are not generally written with a capital letter.

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: The difference in bond lengths is not dramatic: ethane: 109.1 pm, ethene: 108.6 pm, ethyne: 106.3 pm. https://cccbdb.nist.gov/exp2x.asp?casno=74840&charge=0, https://cccbdb.nist.gov/exp2x.asp?casno=74840&charge=0, https://cccbdb.nist.gov/exp2x.asp

Comment: You can find a good and simple explanation [here](https://byjus.com/question-answer/why-are-alkynes-more-acidic-than-alkanes-and-alkenes/).